# Is it possible to force RequireJS to reload text dependency?

Tags: javascript, json, requirejs

I want to use RequireJS to get data from server in JSON format. I request data from different sources and than display it in the callback. Like this:

```
require(
  ['text!/api/services/', 'text!/api/categories/1/'],
  function(services_json, category_json) {
    var services = $.parseJSON(services_json);
    var category = $.parseJSON(category_json);
    // displaying services and category.
  }
);
```

My problem is that from time to time I need to reload some objects (if they have been changed), but RequireJS will not request it second time, because it doesn't know that data has been changed. Is it possible to force it to reload some data? or remove this data from "cache"?

Answer (score 0):

Pulling in JSON sounds like a typical use case for models in [backbonejs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/).
You might want to look into that. I am not aware of any way to reload with requirejs.

Come to think of it... why dont you use jQuery AJAX requests, to get the JSON from time to time?